# Is there a free GUI management tool for Oracle Database Express?

Tags: oracle

Like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for MSSQL?

Comment: The option we use at our office is DBVisualizer. It works with a large number of different database vendors. https://www.dbvis.com/

Comment: Please try dbForge Studio for Oracle GUI tool at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/download.html . Free Express Edition is available.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, there is [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), which is maintained by Oracle.

> Oracle SQL Developer is a free
>   graphical tool for database
>   development. With SQL Developer, you
>   can browse database objects, run SQL
>   statements and SQL scripts, and edit
>   and debug PL/SQL statements. You can
>   also run any number of provided
>   reports, as well as create and save
>   your own. SQL Developer enhances
>   productivity and simplifies your
>   database development tasks.
>
> SQL Developer can connect to any
>   Oracle Database version 10g and later
>   and runs on Windows, Linux and Mac
>   OSX.

Comment: That tool is wicked slow for me.  I want a PHP admin tool like phpMyAdmin, but for Oracle.  I tried "Adminer" but it's not working for me.

Comment: How does one do a backup and restore with it?

Comment: The worst tool for database management i have ever seen.

Comment: @Xplosive That's how I feel about Oracle ;)

Answer (score 27):

There are a few options:

- [Database.net](http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm) is a windows GUI to connect to many different types of databases, oracle included.
- [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is a free tool from Oracle.
- [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is a java based client that can connect to any database that uses JDBC drivers.

I'm sure there are others out there that you could use too...

Answer (score 12):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 9):

you can always use the web based management tool that comes with oracle express db.. have tried using it? you can access it through http://host:port/apex if i remember correctly...

Alternative solutions are Oracle SQL Developer, TOAD etc...

Comment: Toad is universal and being there for a long time now. Its stable and gives you alot of control.

Answer (score 6):

SQLTools is an almost fully functional **and free** Oracle GUI:

http://www.sqltools.net/

Answer (score 3):

You could try this: it's a very good tool, very fast and effective.

http://code.google.com/p/oracle-gui/

Comment: Can you explain to me how can I run this?

Answer (score 2):

Try odbTools at http://odbtools.software.informer.com - it is free.

odbTools is set of integrated GUI tools to manage, administer, monitor and tune the Oracle database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : https://code.google.com/p/oracle-gui/

Haven't used it yet, but looks good though.

Comment: Probably better served as a comment in the case of a 2 year old question with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

[VSQL++ for Oracle](http://www.sqlpp.com/products/oracle-management) is a simplify database management for oracle.

Comment: @Jacket not free, right?